# How to simulate random Y numbers from a linear model with specific X and residuals?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I want to find a way to randomly generate 100 Y values from a linear model where

```
Yi=  2−8Xi+ ei
```

I want the residuals (ei) to come from a normal distribution with a specified mean and variance and X to be a vector of values from 1:100.

I know how to generate random variates using rnorm() but I'm not sure how to approach this more advanced matter. Any ideas for how I can specify the parameters I need would be welcome.

Comment: `Y <- 2 - 8 * (X <- 1:100) + rnorm(100, sd = 0.1)`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
X <- 1:100
Y <-  2 − 8 * X + rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 2)

str(Y)
#num [1:100] -3.51 -12.03 -21.05 -31.38 -36.46 ...
```

Comment: No, residuals of a linear model always have a zero mean.

Comment: this answers the question

Comment: In case anyone wonders [this is the mathematical explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494181/why-the-sum-of-residuals-equals-0-when-we-do-a-sample-regression-by-ols) as to why the mean will always be zero.